# node.js REST client for JHipster application

Tags: node.js, rest, jhipster

I have generated **jhipster** web-app, it comes with **REST APIs**.

Now, I would like to integrate an *existing* **node.js** application to jhipster web-app.

Is there a way to generate a rest-jhipster-client from existing jhipster app? Instead of manually creating functions and calls? Currently using  [node-rest-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client) for this

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JHipster exposes your REST API documentation using swagger.

So you should look for swagger codegen to generate your client code from swagger JSON specification file, for your Jhipster app it is available at `/v2/api-docs` URL.

I'm not a nodejs expert but you could have a look at this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-js-codegen

Comment: Wow! Great, thank you! That is what I was looking for.